# Minimal ideal in a ring which is generated by an idempotent element.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, direct-sum, idempotents

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $M$ be a minimal ideal of $R$ such that $M = Re$ where $e$ is an idempotent element in $R$. Then $R = Re \oplus R(1-e) $

I am not able to see, in order to write $R = Re \oplus R(1-e) $ , where is the fact that $e$ is an idempotent element is used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is minimal ideal for you? Normally $(0)$ is the only minimal ideal.

Comment: No not always. see Brauer's lemma in this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_ideal)

Comment: That's a concept for non commutative rings. The decomposition as a direct sum does not depend on the notion of minimal ideals in the commutative case.

Comment: @Bernard as maximal ideals are forbidden from being the whole ring, the standard definition requires that minimal ideals are not zero. This goes out the window for minimal prime ideals, though....

Comment: And nothing here depends on the minimality, anyhow. It's true for any right/left ideal generated by an idempotent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have $R=I\oplus J$, we need to know that $I+J = R$ and $I\cap J = (0)$.

$eR + (e-1)R=R$ is true for any $e\in R$, since $e-(e-1)=1$.

$eR\cap (e-1)R=(0)$ is where we use idempotence.  If $x=ae=b(e-1)$, then $ex = ae^2=ae=x$, but $ex=b(e-1)e=b(e^2-e)=b(e-e)=0$, and therefore $x=0$.

Comment: This is the same proof as I posted for the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

$Re\cap R(1-e)=\{0\}$:

Indeed if $x$ lies in the intersection, it can be written both as
$x=ae=b(1-e)$ for some $a, b\in R$. But then 
$$x=ae=ae^2=b(1-e)e=b(e-e^2)=b\cdot0=0.$$

Comment: I meant $b(e-e^2)$. Thanks for  pointing the typo! It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Pierce decomposition](http://www.tricki.org/article/Decompose_your_ring_using_idempotents), which says that for an idempotent $e\in R$ we have
$$
 R=eRe \oplus eR(1-e) \oplus (1-e)Re \oplus (1-e)R(1-e).
$$
For commutative rings it simplifies to $R=Re\oplus R(1-e)$. One uses $e^2=e$ several times in the proof, see the above link, e.g., $e(1-e)=e-e^2=0$.